# Is there an way to get responsive background image on my html div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue and can't solve it properly. There is a header with registration form, but I can't do background image responsive. I've read a lot of manulas but it doesn't work.

```css
   .background-img {
   background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/1920/655/');
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
  }
```

```html
             <div class="landing background-img">
             <div class="overlay">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <!-- /.main title -->
                            <h1 class="wow fadeInLeft text-center">
                                Header phrase
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.signup form -->
                        <div id="reg">
                            <div class="col-md-5 ">
                                <div class="signup-header wow fadeInUp">
                                    <h2 class="form-title text-center"     id="signup_title">Register</h2>
                                    <form class="form-header" role="form"     method="POST" id="#">
                                        <div class="form-group" id="mask">
                                            <input class="form-control input-lg" name="username" id="phone_reg" type="text" placeholder="Phone" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control input-lg" name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Pass" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group last" id="reg_block">
                                            <input class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg" id='popup_login_in_pass' onclick="getPassForPhone()" value="GetPass">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="is_send_sms" onclick="showIsSMSEnter(this)">&nbsp;<span id="is_send_sms_label">SMS is here</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group last">
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg" id='enter' value="Enter">
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="error_reg_result text-center">some text</p>
                                        <small class="time_reg_result" style="display: none">SMS will come after <span class="time_reg_sms">60</span> sec.</small><br>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If I change background-size: cover; to background-size: contain; image become responsive but it change height even if i set it to height: 100%;

How can I achive my goal?

Comment: pls share a demo link

Comment: the code you have provided looks broken, please create a minimal representation of your problem.

Comment: can you tell me the size of your image ?

Comment: @HUSSAIN, 1920x655

Comment: @JoykalInfotech, https://codepen.io/nashgc/pen/pBqBjw

Comment: When you say 'responsive' I guess you want to maintain the image's aspect ratio. So now you have to decide if you want your image 'cropped' (this way parts of the image won't be seen depending on screen dimensions) or if you want your image fully shown  (which will leave blank spaces depending on screen dimensions).

Comment: @NashGC at which screen size your background is showing white spaces?

Comment: its working fine for 1920*1600 for me

Comment: @DIe, I think I already have the first variant, because when I decrease window size, right part of my image stay at the same place, it look like 'crop'.

Comment: @HUSSAIN, I have 1920x1080 screen resosution, and if I change window size even for 15% I have bottom space.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use background-size:contain

```
  .background-img {
        background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/1920/655/');
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: size:contain;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).